# Создать объект с вложенными классами

Tags: c#

Мне надо в одном списке хранить как общие параметры, так и пользовательские параметры. Для этого я использую вложенные классы. Вот для примера

```
class Parameters
{
    public class UserParameters
    {
        string testUserParameters;
    }

    public class AllPrameters
    {
        string testAllParameters;
    }
}
```

Но когда я создаю объект класса Parameters. Я не могу ему назначить параметры вложенных классов. Например, `testUserParameters`

```
class Test
{
    static void x()
    {          
        Parameters g = new Parameters();        
    }         
}
```

Что делать? Если не понятно зачем я это делаю, поясняю. Мне надо хранить параметры программы в одном конфигурационном файле.

Пример: допустим мне надо хранить сотрудников компании. Я в одном конфигурационном файле храню общие данные: количество сотрудников, количество отделов, название всех отделов...

А также храню данные о каждом человеке. ФИО, отдел, возраст... И здесь я создаю объект когда мне нужны общие данные я в объекте заполняю только общие данные, а когда я заполняю данные на сотрудника я в объекте заполняю только данные на сотрудника и храню это в общем списке.

Comment: в классе Parameters нет ни одного поля или свойства. Так что именно ты хочешь назначить?

Comment: я хочу назначить "g" параметры вложенных классов. Вот как это сделать?

Comment: ты создаешь только экземпляр класса _Parameters_. В этом классе **нет ни одного** поля. Соответственно и назначать нечего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подклассы описали, но и только, сами то их как члены класса объявите хотя бы для начала:

```
class Parameters
{
   public class UserParameters
   {   
      string testUserParameters;
   }

    public class AllPrameters
    {
       string testAllParameters;
    }

    public UserParameters up;
    public AllPrameters ap;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, до самого меня это не дошло

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понимаю зачем делать вложенные классы, точнее какую выгоду вы от этого получите.

В вашем случае я бы сделал так :

```
public class UserParameters
{
    public string testUserParameters { get; set; }
}

public class AllPrameters
{
    public string testAllParameters { get; set; }
}

public class Parameters
{
    public Parameters()
    {
        userParameters = new UserParameters();
        allPrameters = new AllPrameters();
    }

    public UserParameters userParameters;
    public AllPrameters allPrameters;
}
```

//вызов

```
Parameters g = new Parameters();
g.userParameters.testUserParameters = "test";
```

Answer (score 1):

У членов ваших вложенных классов не выставлены модификаторы видимости. То есть по умолчанию они `private`. Соответственно вы не можете обращаться к этим членам извне, в том числе и из внешнего класса Parameters (внешний класс не имеет доступа к приватным членам внутреннего, тогда как внутренний может обращаться к  закрытым членам внешнего класса).

А вообще возникает вопрос необходимости вложенных классов в данном случае. Вложенные классы - это довольно специфическая сущность, и реальная необходимость в них возникает нечасто. Попробуйте сами себе ответить на вопрос: что именно в вашем случае можно реализовать (или проще реализовать) с помощью вложенных классов, но нельзя с помощью обычных, не вложенных? Подозреваю, что ничего

Comment: изменил все параметры на public не помогло

Comment: @polsok а что конкретно у вас происходит? Ошибки компиляции, рантайма или что?

Comment: ну вы сами можете его запустить в визуал. Когда вы пытаетесь заполнить параметры "g". У вас не выскочат никакие варианты вложенных классов.

Comment: @polsok у вас сейчас фактически есть один пустой класс, содержащий два почти пустых вложенных класса. У вас нет никакого кода инициализации для этих вложенных классов, нет конструкторов, нет методов. В приведённом вами коде вы создаёте экземпляр внешнего класса и больше ничего. У вас там нет вообще никакой инициализации, кроме вызова конструктора по умолчанию, соответственно, у вас ни откуда не возьмутся эти "параметры" у вашего "g" (у него и "параметров"-то никаких нет кстати).

Comment: хорошо, можете исправить мой пример?

Comment: @polsok в том-то и дело, что сложно понять, чего вы хотите добиться и какое "исправление" вам нужно. Вы очень туманно описываете свою проблему. Например что вы подразумеваете под "параметрами"?

Answer (score 0):

Вы говорите про список, не подойдет ли вам IDictionary? То есть пары имя/значение для параметров.

```
class Parameters {
    IDictionary<string, string> _userParameters;
    IDictionary<string, string> _allParameters;
    //...
}
```

**UPD:**

Во-первых, сейчас у вас нет списков.

Во-вторых, зачем вам внутренние классы? Их обычно используют для сокрытия каких-то сервисных типов внутри публичного типа. Если нужна аггрегация, то это делается иначе - через членство экземпляров одного типа в другом. (это не JavaScript)

В-третьих, нет прямой зависимости "один тип - один файл", родственность для (де)сериализации выражается через аггрегацию.

```
class A { }
class B { }

class C {
    public A a { get; set; }
    public B b { get; set; }
}

var jsonData = File.ReadAllText("myFile.json");
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C>(jsonData);
```

Comment: не представляю как его можно тут использовать. 
Добавил пример в вопросе для лучшего понимания

Comment: @polsok Добавил кое-что.